# Spring MVC 4 Thymeleaf 3 HTTP Status 404 - Resource not found

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

[image]

I found posts with similar title in stackoverflow, but one way or the other those were missing some configurations or some pitflow in their files. I'm posting this because I have made all the possible corrections, still couldn't make this work. My code is given below:

web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>home.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
    <import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rahul.*"/>

</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Thymeleaf Template Engine (Spring4-specific version) -->
    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolvers">
            <set>
                <ref bean="templateResolver" />
            </set>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Thymeleaf Template Resolver -->
    <bean id="templateResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

AppController.java

```html
package com.rahul.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class AppController {

   @RequestMapping("/hello")
   public String indexRediect(Model model){
       model.addAttribute("name","Rahul");
       return "hello";
   }

}
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>

    <title>Hello Spring MVC</title>

    <!--<link th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <h2 th:text="Sample Page"></h2>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/hello}" method="post">
        <p>Id: <input type="text"/></p>
        <p>Message: <input type="text"/></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

hello.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <meta name="description" content=""/>
    <meta name="author" content=""/>

    <title>Hello Spring MVC</title>

    <!--<link th:href="@{/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet"/>-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <h2 th:text="'Hello ' + ${name} + '!'"></h2>

</div>
<!-- /container -->
<!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script th:src="@{/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried altering the html folder path in applicationcontext xml as well as in project build path. But no luck.

Comment: I recently wrote a blog post on deploying a Spring MVC app to Tomcat without the need for Web.xml and with Java based configuration. It can be found [here](https://sanaulla.info/2017/11/18/how-to-deploy-spring-application-without-web-xml-to-tomcat/)

Comment: try removing the .* in the component scan base packages

Comment: I'm not looking for java based configuration, I just wanted to figure out why its failing in my example.

Comment: hy, did you get answer of the question ? i am facing the same probelm

Comment: No, no one answered until now.